# jQuery form fields clearing on Click

Tags: jquery, forms, click

I created a form with a dialog search box for a Street Address and one for a Postal address. How it works is when you click on the search result it populates either the Street or Postal address depending on which button you clicked. It's all working fine, except when you click on a search result it clears the field population for the other address. As far as I can tell this is all linked to the click function. ANy help will be greatly appreciated, thanks

*For example:*
If I click on the Postal address button and click a search result it will populate the postal address fields. Then if I click the Street address button, it will populate the Street address fields but also clear the Postal address fields.

**Code**

```
<!-- STREET ADDRESS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table-data tr').click(function () {
      var curRowClass = $(this).attr("class");
      $('#street_name').val( $('.' + curRowClass + ' td.address_street').text() );
      $('#suburb').val( $('.' + curRowClass + ' td.address_suburb').text() );
      $('#city').val( $('.' + curRowClass + ' td.address_city').text() );
      $("#modal_form").dialog('close');
    });
  });
</script>

<!-- POSTAL ADDRESS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table-data tr').click(function () {
      var curRowClass = $(this).attr("class");
      $('#street_name_classy').val( $('.' + curRowClass + ' td.address_street_classy').text() );
      $('#suburb_classy').val( $('.' + curRowClass + ' td.address_suburb_classy').text() );
      $('#city_classy').val( $('.' + curRowClass + ' td.address_city_classy').text() );
      $("#modal_form").dialog('close');
    });
  });
</script>
```

I can post more code if you need but I've narrowed it down to his click function, in this script that is causing the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys, I ended up solving it using $('#table-data_classy tr').live('click',function () cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I ended up solving it using

```
$('#table-data tr').live('click',function ()
```

cheers

Answer (score 2):

You're hooking up two event handlers (two `click` handlers) to the same selector (`#table-data tr`).  So when you click the button (looks like the same button), it's going to fire both click handlers.

I'm not sure how you're getting your data, but you should consider either having two different handlers and some sort of flag to determine which branch gets fired.

```
$('#table-data tr').click(function () {
  if(do_street_address_work) {
    //your logic for populating the street address
  } else {
    //your logic for populating the postal address
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, I did have 2 buttons but any way I found the solution in a related question using the live('click', function () Thanks for the input, cheers

Answer (score 2):

Realize that both handlers are firing with a row click.

If the issue is that loading one address clears the addresses set in the other rows, the problem is that your jquery selector is selecting every field, not just the correct one.  You can use the this variable to limit your selectors to the row which fired the click event:

```
<!-- STREET ADDRESS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table-data tr').click(function () {
      var $row = $(this);

      $('#street_name').val( $row.find('td.address_street').text() );
      $('#suburb').val( $row.find('td.address_suburb').text() );
      $('#city').val( $row.find('td.address_city').text() );
      $("#modal_form").dialog('close');
    });
  });
</script>
```

If the issue is that setting the street address clears the postal address, the problem is that your click handler is on the row, not the button.  You didn't post your HTML, but the general idea is:

```
<!-- STREET ADDRESS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table-data tr .street-button').click(function () {
      var $row = $(this).parents('tr').first();

      $('#street_name').val( $row.find('td.address_street').text() );
      $('#suburb').val( $row.find('td.address_suburb').text() );
      $('#city').val( $row.find('td.address_city').text() );
      $("#modal_form").dialog('close');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Zack, I did try that already and it didn't work out, I just found the solution through a related question that popped up on the side

    $('#table-data_classy tr').live('click',function () {

This solved my problem, thanks for the input cheers

Answer (score 1):

For both of Postal Address and Street Address buttons, I think both event handler will be called mainly you set both handler like this:

```
 $('#table-data tr').click(function ()
```

So you need to have more specific selector than this.

Comment: Thanks Sheen, I solved it using a related question using the live('click', function () Thanks for the input, cheers